# Getting a Harvard-style list of references using Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, harvard-style

I've been dabbling with `biblatex` because I'm using TeXpad on the iPad. I have managed, I think, except for one thing: the final references are all numbered in the sequence they were used rather than alphabetically. I tried `[labelnumber=false]` but that just had `[]` preceding entries;). I also can't work out how to suppress the URL field.

Simple example: I'm getting this:

> [1] Mary Douglas. How institutions think. 1st. Syracuse, N.Y.: Syracuse University Press, 1986. url: http://www.routledge.com/books/details/9 780415684781/.

When I want:

> M. Douglas (1986). How institutions think. Syracuse
>   University Press, Syracuse, N.Y., 1st edn.

Also, this should be ordered under `Douglas`.

All the other questions I've found relate only to citing within the actual text, not the final reference list.

-- added after first response.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{textest.bib}
@BOOK{douglas1986a,
author = {Douglas, Mary},
title = {How Institutions Think},
year = {1986},
publisher = {Syracuse UP},
address = {Syracuse, NY},
url = {http://www.routledge.com/books/details/9780415684781}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{textest.bib}

\begin{document}
Religion does not explain. Religion has to be explained. \autocite{douglas1986a}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I think, given my workload, that working through to specify the details of the output is going to be more than I can do with my deadline so I'll tinker on the next paper, and keep a note of your advice for then...

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  As far as I know, there is no 'Harvard' style implemented yet, but there are many 'author-year' styles available; one of them might not be too difficult to tweak.  As for the 'numerical' reference you are getting, it is because that is the default option.  Try adding the option `style=authoryear` and you'll get something more in tune with the Harvard style guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex` implements the two major versions of so-called [Harvard style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_style) (author-date and author-title) in its `authoryear` and `authortitle` schemes, both of which in turn come in a variety of sub-flavours (`authoryear-ibid` etc.). You might want to have a look at the [examples](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex//doc/examples), choose the scheme that best suits your needs, and then customize as necessary. As jon [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108605/getting-a-harvard-style-list-of-references-using-biblatex#comment237839_108605), plain `authoryear` with no extras might be a good starting point.

> I also can't work out how to suppress the URL field.

that's managed via the `url` option:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
  url=false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest available is Chicago style. I do the following:

```
\usepackage{natbib}

%...

\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\bibliography{bibex1}
```

And then in the actual text you can reference as `\citet{}` for author (year) and `\citealp{}` for author, year. The references/bibliography comes up exactly how it should for Harvard referencing.

Comment: this will be of limited use to the OP, as they are (and probably want to continue) using `biblatex`. So I don't think going back to old `bibtex/natbib` is a good idea, particularly since `biblatex` comes with [several versions](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex//doc/examples) of what's commonly referred to as ›the‹ Harvard style.